# If I buy Civilization 5: Brave New World, will I be able to play Vanilla?

Tags: civilization-5

If I buy Civilization 5: Brave New World, will I be able to play vanilla Civilization 5.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Brave new world is an expansion to vanilla, so you need to own the base game in order to play Brave New World.

The game does give you the option to turn off expansions and run the game in vanilla if you so desire.

Comment: So I would need Civilization 5 to play BNW. What if I just buy BWN, that won't work right?

Comment: @Wulfinite Correct, Brave new world is an expansion to the base game and will not function as a stand-alone game.

Comment: @Wulfinite do yourself a favor and don't play Vanilla. BNW fixed a *lot* of problems, especially AI related.

Comment: Depending on distribution, expansion of a game may have main game included, which usually is reflected in both description and a pricetag

Comment: When we talk about BNW, we *are* referring to G&K *and* BNW, I hope...

Comment: No just BNW. So would you say that there is a big difference between Vanilla and BNW?

Answer (score 23):

Yes. Simply select DLC from the main menu and disable the expansions.
[image]

[image]